# PHP imagemagick convert PDF to JPEG with originals and thumbs

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, jpeg, imagick

I need to convert multipages PDF to JPEG with original resolution and thumbs. I succesfully set thumbs width and height, but I can't setOriginal width and height for original jpg image.

```
   for($i=0; $i<= $pages-1; $i++){
        $query = "INSERT into `clients_important_docs` values(null, '".intval($pole->ids)."', 'pdf','".Time()."')";
        $id = $db->insert($query);
        $im = new Imagick();
        $im->setResolution(100, 100);
        $im->readimage("users/".$dir."/".$folder."/".($ide)."_original.pdf[".$i."]");   
        $im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
        $im->writeImage("users/".$dir."/".$folder."/".($id)."_original.jpg");       
        $im->clear();
        $im->destroy();


        $im = new Imagick();
        $im->setResolution(50, 50);
        $im->readimage("users/".$dir."/".$folder."/".($ide)."_original.pdf[".$i."]");   
        $im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
        $im->writeImage("users/".$dir."/".$folder."/".($id).".jpg");        
        $im->clear();
        $im->destroy();



        }
```

Original's saves now with thumbs width and height. Thanks

Comment: Why do you read the image and destroy it and then read the same image again? Read it once, write the hi-res JPEG first, then downsize and write the low-res image.

Comment: Ok, i change the code, but still nothink...

Comment: You probably mean `resizeImage()` rather than `setResolution()`... http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php

Comment: Yea, I completed that, but with another way, I will update this post, and show u how I done this.

Comment: Ok so I updated question, working well, but I must recount pixels to % with ratio of images (16:9, 16:10 etc... )